# What is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $\beta \mathbb{R}$ is Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. What is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dense subset of a dense subset is a dense subset.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The natural inclusion $i: \mathbb R \rightarrow \beta \mathbb R$ is an embedding. So $\overline{i(\mathbb Q)}\supset i(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Then the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the whole space $\beta \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Paul, yes that's right.